# How to find the sum of values present in one table and missing in other table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to find the sum of the values corresponding to a key that is present in Table 1 but not in Table 2.

[image]

These tables have been created based on some filters and represent the values on 2 different dates.

The two different dates are chosen from 2 different date tables which have an inactive relationship, specially created for this purpose.

I want to create a measure that finds out the sum.

Below is the syntax I have used:

```
 Difference = 
VAR 
Table1 = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('TableA'[Id]), 'TableA'[Type] = "ABC", ALL('Date'), USERELATIONSHIP('Date'[As of Date], Previous_Date[Previous_Date]),USERELATIONSHIP('Date'[As of Date], 'TableA'[As of Date]))
VAR
Table2 = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('TableA'[Id]), 'TableA'[Type] = "ABC", USERELATIONSHIP('Date'[As of Date], 'TableA'[As of Date]))
RETURN
IF(AND(VALUES('TableA'[Id]) IN Table1 , NOT(VALUES('TableA'[Id])) IN Table2), 
CALCULATE(SUM('TableA'[Values])),0)
```

It is error-free. However, when I drop the measure on a KPI visual, I am getting the following message:

[image]

Please tell me what is wrong with the syntax. Also, please let me know if there is any better code that can be written.

Kindly help.

Comment: can you please provide a sample .pbix?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am somewhat new to stack overflow and don't know how I can. Please tell me how I would be able to upload it.

Comment: You can simply upload the file to dropbox and provide a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting an error is that it expects a single value for `x` when you write `x IN Table1` but using the `VALUES` function can return a list rather than a single value.

I'd try something more like this after the `RETURN`:

```
SUMX (
    'TableA',
    IF ( 'TableA'[Id] IN Table1 && NOT ( 'TableA'[Id] IN Table2 ), 'TableA'[Value] )
)
```

This iterates through each row of `TableA` and checks if the `Id` value in each row is in the tables you calculated. If the condition is met, it adds the `Value`. Otherwise `IF` returns a blank (which is treated the same as `0` in a sum) since there is no third argument.